# Interpret an HTML form value as a list in a Flask view

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to set a hidden form field to a list of values, then use the list when the form is submitted.  However, the value seems to be a string instead of a list.  How do I use get list I passed to the form as a list?

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('action') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="list" value="{{ some_list }}"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```
@app.route('/action', methods=['POST'])
def action():
    elements = request.form['list']
    list_length = len(elements)
    ...
```

Comment: I wonder what is the point of doing this. You're obviously passing `some_list` into the template into the first place, in order to render it; so you already have it on the server, why pass it through to the client and back again? Better store it somewhere like the session between requests.

Comment: I guess this is what I was trying to confirm. So parsing is the only option then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an HTML form is submitted from a client, it sends the field values as strings.  Assuming the value you will enter in this field looks like `abc, def, 123, foo`, then you just split the value on `,` and strip any surrounding whitespace.

```
elements = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in request.form['list'].split(',')) if y]
```

---

Rather than passing/parsing a value back and forth in a hidden form field, what you're probably looking for is the session.  That allows you to store JSON serializable values across requests.

```
elements = session.get('elements', [])  # get existing data
elements.append(len(data))  # do something to the data
session['elements'] = data  # store the new data
```